# Batch Import Neo4j Unique Nodes With Labels

Tags: batch-file, import, neo4j, constraints, unique

I could not figure out a way to add labels to nodes during batch import, I have written a task to export all users from mysql to neo4j, I have added a constraint on userId. I have modified the batch to accept labels, It works perfectly fine. Now, since every userId is unique the batch import works fine, but i have another table as skills, I have added a constraint on the skill name, For multiple users there could be similar skill names, now since the skill name is not unique , my batch update fails. I want to know if there's a way to add multiple skills in the batch import and having a constraint on skill name. I would also like to know if there's another way to adding labels during batch import.

```
task :create_graph => :environment do
    people = []
    neo = Neography::Rest.new

    puts "Fetching Candidates"
    User.all.each do |user|
      begin
        people << { :userId => user.id, :firstName => user.first_name }
      rescue Exception => e
        puts e.message
      end
    end

    puts "Creating Candidate Nodes"
    people_nodes = {}
    people.each_slice(100) do |slice|
      commands = []
      slice.each_with_index do |person, index|
        commands << [:create_unique_node_with_label, "UserIndex", "userId", person[:userId], person]
      end
      label = ["CANDIDATE"]
      puts commands
      batch_results = neo.batch(label,*commands)
    end

  end
```

Here is the modified code in the batch.rb file i have modified in the gem.

```
def do_batch(label,*args)
        batch = []
        Array(args).each_with_index do |c, i|
          batch << {:id => i }.merge(get_batch(c))
          if c[0]==:create_unique_node_with_label
            batch << {:to => "{"+i.to_s+"}/labels",:body => label,:method => "POST"}
          end
        end
        options = {
          :body => batch.to_json,
          :headers => json_content_type
        }
        puts options
        @connection.post("/batch", options)
      end

def batch_create_unique_node_with_label(index, key, value, properties)
        post "/index/node/%{index}?unique" % {:index => index} do
          {
              :key        => key,
              :value      => value,
              :properties => properties
          }
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

The unique indexes you are using are for the legacy indexing in Neo4j. I would suggest you have a look at the new uniqueness constraints in Neo4j 2.0, creating a constraint like

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Candidate) ASSERT n.name IS UNIQUE;
```

And then using the cypher MERGE feature to do get-or-create on unique things:

```
MERGE (n:Candidate {name:"some name"})
// And then do more things with n here
```

As a further aside, you can do batching of these cypher queries using the new transactional endpoint:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html